# How to make element in svg not stretched by viewbox?

Tags: svg

This example draw two circle in a box sized 10 x 10.

```
<svg width="10" height="10" viewbox="0 0 10 10">
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="2" fill="purple" /> <!-- circle A-->
    <circle cx="4" cy="4" r="2" fill="purple" /> <!-- circle B-->
</svg>
```

Circle A have same size as circle B. Suppose i want to resize the svg to 100 x 100 like this:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 10 10">
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="2" fill="purple" /> <!-- circle A-->
    <circle cx="4" cy="4" r="2" fill="purple" /> <!-- circle B-->
</svg>
```

The size of circles will resized. How to make specific element inside svg, lets say circle A only, so it is not affected to the resize.

Comment: Use two svg elements, one of which doesn't have a viewBox. Place them over each other using CSS positioning.

Comment: @RobertLongson i can use this solution, but it need to resize my cx and cy object depend on the svg width and height, isn't it? is there better solutions? since my actual code is complex

Comment: I've no idea what your first sentence means.

Comment: My objects has fixed coordinates. When i change overall size, i just set the width and height. Your solution seems need many attribute to change just to resize. If i'm wrong please give me example as comment, i will very appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made another sample. I use nested svg element to split effect of viewBox. You can place shape nodes relative position by using percentage value, but this technique is not useful for general path shapes. Since, I use "use" element to split shape definition and positioning.

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <defs>
        <!--shape definition-->
        <circle r="2" fill="red" id="circleA"/> <!-- circle A-->
    </defs>
    <!--parcentage positioning by viewport-->
    <use x="20%" y="20%" xlink:href="#circleA"/>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
        <circle cx="4" cy="4" r="2" fill="purple" /> <!-- circle B-->
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 10 10">
    <rect x="2" y="2" width="0.001" height="0.001" 
        stroke="red" stroke-width="4" stroke-linejoin="round" 
        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/> <!-- circle A-->
    <circle cx="4" cy="4" r="2" fill="purple" /> <!-- circle B-->
</svg>
```

But I don't know every browser supports vector-effect property.

Comment: is there any attribute such as `vector-effect="non-scaling-width-and-stroke"` ? the rect's size is scaled when svg width and height are changed.

Comment: No UA has implemented any other vector-effect.